# Firebase phone authentication not working after creating .apk file

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I initialized a react native app with Expo Bare Workflow, installed the @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/auth package and followed all the setup instructions from the rnfirebase.io website. When I'm in development the firebase phone number authentication works fine but when I build using EAS (Expo Application Services) the reCAPTCHA screen doesn't open and I don't get the code of confirmation.

I need help to solve this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840408/react-recaptcha-google-not-showing-at-all

if the above doesn't fix your issue try adding the internet permission in your manifest